# Assign anonymous in IF-ELSE statements

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, anonymous-types

Please consider this code :

```
 var Final = result.OrderBy(p => p.AreaCode).ThenBy(p => p.PCode).Skip(PageSize * (PageNo - 1)).Take(PageSize);
  if (PageSize == 0)
  {
      Final = result.OrderBy(p => p.AreaCode).ThenBy(p => p.PCode);
  }
```

Because anonymous types should assign to an expression I can't write it this way :

```
   var Final ;
   if(PageSize > 0 )
   {
      Final =  result.OrderBy(p => p.AreaCode).ThenBy(p => p.PCode).Skip(PageSize * (PageNo - 1)).Take(PageSize);
   }
  else
  {
      Final = result.OrderBy(p => p.AreaCode).ThenBy(p => p.PCode);
  }
```

How I can write above ugly code better?

thanks

Comment: Why would you like to make that code "better"?

Comment: @Mobstaa : because I'm Idealistic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it better like below:

```
var Final = result.OrderBy(p => p.AreaCode).ThenBy(p => p.PCode);

if (PageSize > 0)
    Final = Final.Skip(PageSize * (PageNo - 1)).Take(PageSize);
```